# PHP - Getting information from link itself rather than GET parameters?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Consider a situation of a URL as:

```
www.example.com/softwares/download.php?f=firefox&v=13
```

It does not look as good as URL:

```
www.example.com/softwares/firefox/download?v=13
```

or same `download.php` used as:

```
www.example.com/softwares/chrome/download?v=20
```

How can I achieve this type of URL filtering in PHP?

Some point I want to covered here:

1. I don't need a folder-hierarchy here like having different folders for `/firefox/` and different for `/chrome/`
2. There could be only two PHP files (*as I wish to*) for all products: `/software/software-info.php` and `/software/download.php` (already got [here](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php/)).
3. I am able to put and fetch information from database in PHP but just want to have different link for different product.

I am a Java Web Developer in which you have `Filters` to get information from a part of link and redirect the request accordingly.

I am new in PHP programming and if this question is already asked or obvious than please pardon me and provide that question link.

Answer (score 2):

This is ideally what you should use url rewriting (mod-rewrite in .htaccess) for.
Your visitor navigates to:

```
www.example.com/softwares/firefox/download?v=13
```

or even

```
www.example.com/softwares/firefox/13/
```

but your server will understand it as:

```
www.example.com/softwares/download.php?f=firefox&v=13
```

Comment: Will using `mod-rewrite` redirects the user to new page or it just forward the request internally?

Comment: It depends what flags you set. Iirc [NC] will be silent (i.e. internal only), [R=301] would redirect the user. Though I'm no expert on those flags you should check the documentation to be sure.

Comment: Hey @Bob I am unable to convert your help into working..:( googled also but could not find relevant resource..could you please point me on any nice documented article about it? Or code to achieve this?

Comment: Search for an introduction to mod_rewrite. It's like top10 of tech things discussed on the internet (since a lot of SEO relies on it) and you should have no trouble at all finding places to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use htaccess files to do URL rewriting. Essentially this would allow you to take the segments of the url after /software/ and pass them ass parameters to be controlled by the software script.

There are also a bunch of PHP frameworks which use 'routes'. They're based on a similar principal as URL rewriting. I'd recommend Codeigniter as a good starting point - it's a straightforward framework, which plenty of documentation and tutorials.

Good luck!